# Button onClick event not being triggered in React application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify

I have the following application code:

```
'use strict';

//function to handle gapi initialization
var init = function() {
   //load plus api
  gapi.client.load('plus' , 'v1' , function() {
    gapi.isReady = true;
  });
}

window.init = init;

var React = require('React'),
    aapi = require('./components/alonso-api'),
    BlogList = require('./components/blog-list'),
    ActivityBox = require('./components/activity-box'),
    GoogleSignin = require('./components/google-signin');    

if (!window.React) {
  window.React = React;
}

React.render(<BlogList data={aapi.blogs.read()} /> , document.getElementById('blog-list'));

React.render(<ActivityBox data={aapi.blogs.read({
  offset : 0,
  limit : 3
})} /> , document.getElementById('activity-box'));

React.render(<GoogleSignin clientId='client-id' scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'/> , document.getElementById('google-signin'));
```

All React elements are being displayed correctly, but `GoogleSignin`'s `onClick` event is not being triggered. Here is the `GoogleSignin` definition:

```
var React = require('react'),
    window = window || {},
    gapi = window.gapi || {};

var GoogleSignin = React.createClass({
  handleClick : function(e) {
    console.log('click!');
  },
  render : function() {
    return (
      <div className="googleSignin">
        <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleClick}><i className="fa fa-google-plus"></i>  Sign in</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = GoogleSignin;
```

I got the same code running without Browserify and the `button` handler is being handled properly, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Try adding e.preventDefault() in there. Sometimes that helps with strange things like this

Comment: I tried adding e.preventDefault() with no luck, there is no error message in the console, just got some warning messages because i'm rendering an array with no unique key prop, not quite sure whether this could be related though.

Comment: I just ran a simple fiddle with your GoogleSignin component and it worked fine. Perhaps try removing your other components, as well as the gapi init, and only leave GoogleSignin. Maybe something is interfering with that component? And try looking at your button via the React tools (Chrome) and see if your event is attached.